# Benefits of PHP frameworks

Tags: php, frameworks

I have heard a lot about PHP frameworks like ZEND, CodeIgniter,CakePhp etc and i am also well aware of some advantages of using it i.e. increased productivity,reduced errors etc but doesn't php framework make coding a complex process ? Doesn't coding without framework provides more flexibility ? Some people say you don't need any additional framework, as PHP is itself a framework.

So why there is so much usage of PHP framework ? Are frameworks really necessary in PHP?

Comment: At the end of the day these frameworks are tools. Sometimes they are the right tool for the job... sometimes they are not.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Doesn't php framework make coding a complex process?

It depends what you want to do. If all you're doing is creating a basic contact form for a site that is all static HTML, then yes using a framework would make it a more complex process.  On the other hand if you're building a large scale app then using a framework would not necessarily make it more complex.

> Doesn't coding without framework provides more flexibility ?

This depends on the framework itself, they aren't all the same. Some frameworks such as Slim or Codeigniter are very trimmed down and don't get in the way too much and so don't really impact on flexibility, some are more complex such as Symfony2/Zend.

> Some people say you don't need any additional framework, as PHP is itself a framework.

They are right, you technically don't need a framework, you can do anything with plain PHP that you can do with a framework. Frameworks have really evolved from developers personal archives of functions and helper code. PHP can be relatively low level in that it doesn't have a ready made function to do everything you need. Before frameworks, developers tended to have their own set of helper code that would be reused on many projects. Frameworks are still essentially that, except they are collaborative projects that hundreds or thousands of developers contribute to.

One other benefit of frameworks is if you have several developers, and one has developed an application and you want another developer to contribute to it or take over it, then if the developer is familiar with the framework that was used he can get up to speed on the app much quicker than if it was written in plain PHP. Without the framework, the new developer would have to decipher the previous developers system before they even start to look at adding any new functionality.

Answer (score 7):

This is a broad question and I think an important one. I am in the camp of NOT using frameworks unless absolutely necessary. The question is, when is it necessary?

First off, the thing that I think gave me this strange, allergic reaction to frameworks is that inexperienced coders want to use them for EVERYTHING, even tiny sites.... and it's bizarre. Maybe its through some need to make their resumes bigger by saying they've used codeigniter- but in my experience that doesn't make a damn bit of a difference. Hiring managers want SKILLSETS, not somebody that can read API documentation- which anyone can do. If you have working knowledge about program architecture and OOP principles, you're hired. If you don't, but you're a codeigniter ninja, .... eeehhhh.... ok?

Frameworks have their uses but I think when your mom wants to make a website for her bake sale then you can just slap a page together using a much lighter weight system. I don't sit in the camp of belief that you should include code "in case you need it". Over time, I have developed my own framework that is absolutely tiny, which is why every single web site or application I have ever built has ranked in the top 2% (though usually top 1%) of page load times in the world by google.

This is not to say they are bad- just don't go running off to use a framework because you want to put it on your resume- you're actually shooting yourself in the foot in the long run. Why? Because you won't spend time using the language itself, you'll spend time using the language of the framework. Take jQuery for instance- I avoided it for YEARS because it wasn't JAVASCRIPT. People scoffed at it- but now, when I go to a technical interview and I get asked (inevitably): "What is your experience level with jQuery", and I say "not much", and they for a second look surprised, but then I follow it up with "but I just wrote dependency injection via inversion of control in native JS yesterday"- I get hired ON THE SPOT.

Frameworks are great. Just ask yourself if you really need them. Particularly the question is: are the benefits of coding it yourself outweighed by the time benefits (don't forget about the learning curve of the platform) of the framework or not? On the one hand (non-framework approach), you learn a lot, and perhaps you take more time because you're working out your own kinks- but you learned a ton about the language itself (PHP in this case). On the other hand, you learned a new framework and *maybe* got a site up quicker that most likely is slower.

Wordpress is a great example of an overused framework in my opinion. Back in my freelancing days I used to take on gigs that needed me to "revamp a wordpress site"- only to find a site that could barely load because somebody plugged in every plugin they could find and made what was a *stupid simple* site into a tank with ungreased treads. It's OVERKILL in that case.

With my experience in CTO and Tech Lead positions, when somebody puts Wordpress and jQuery as primary points on their resume, to me that says "I don't know a thing about OOP and how to use these languages if required" which, in the real world (and I work on huge projects like windows 8 and other projects of that magnitude) - is OFTEN the case. Microsoft expressly forbids the usage of jQuery in their metro app system for MS released products because they want to show off their system dependency free.

Other companies, however, DO use frameworks. I just got off a project using Foundation and it was AWESOME- but that's because the architect of the project fully researched the framework and we used it RIGHT. The result was a fully responsive pristine code base that went from full monitor glory down to triscuit-sized smartphone screen awesomeness.

**IN SHORT:**

Frameworks, when used right, can be awesome- particularly for large projects (and I'm talking enterprise large). For smaller projects they aren't necessarily bad- but when they are used without thinking about their implementations, its like using a hatchet for a scalpel.

Just my 2 cents.

Comment: Interesting post, but this in particular that caught my eye: _I have developed my own framework_. The usual (and in my view correct) response where that phrase appears in a question here is, no! don't do it! the world doesn't need another one! etc (we see it here often). Whilst it sounds like you know what you're doing, the OP should be aware that, over time, one's "personal library" essentially _becomes_ a framework, except it doesn't have as many features, it's not as well tested, and only a few devs in the world are familiar with it.

Comment: See now thats a nice succinct way of saying it- writing such a broad response forces you to leave out little details like that and I think it's an important distinction. THANKS for that because "it becomes a framework" is basically what I wanted to imply there- you create the tools you need and can include/exclude them because you know they exist, whereas part of the drawback with a big framework is maybe you dont know how to "leave things out" that aren't essential. Thanks!

Comment: The fact that these posts get downvoted is weird to me. These are opinion pieces, why are people downvoting?

Comment: JQuery part , WordPress plugins part, and the mom part is awesome !!

Answer (score 2):

> *Are they necessary in PHP?*

No they are not, sure it is possible to code anything without frameworks. But it's more work, this is like: Why am I using C when I can do all the same by writing assembler?

> *So why there is so much usage of PHP framework?*

The benefits of using frameworks is, that you can use many predefined things. For example, in most PHP frameworks you can use MVC Pattern. Sure you could also build your own MVC structure with flat PHP, but that is like re-inventing the wheel everytime again. Only thing is, if you have **very** specific requirements, you may can/should not use a framework, but in most cases the requirements are not that specific.

The point with MVC is only one of a lot benefits. Depending on the framework you want to use, there are specific benefits.

So, it is just like you said. By using a framework you can save time, because you don't have to re-invent everything that already exists.

You can see a framwork as a **tool**, that helps you to develop better and faster.

**Edit:** Like Ayesh K mentioned in his comment, it is also a benefits, that a framework is developed by many experts, so it normally is better code, following the principle: 'Four eyes see more than two'.

Comment: While this answer focuses on reinventing things, it's also good to mention frameworks are developed by many experts in each niche so you will get better code that what you (usually) code.